# xml file for submitting feed to amazon

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services

This is the xml file for processing  Amazon product via Submit feed.Here the `<ItemType>Wireless</ItemType>`
 always showing product type as MISC_OTHER in Amazon seller central for all item types. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>example</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Product</MessageType>
<PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<Product>
<SKU>R1000TEST</SKU>
<ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
<DescriptionData>
<Title>test_material name</Title>
<Brand>Applexus</Brand>
<Description>test_material name</Description>
<BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
<BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
<MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
<Manufacturer>Applexus</Manufacturer>
<ItemType>Wireless</ItemType>
</DescriptionData>
</Product>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```